# How to make bash command and run it from PHP?

Tags: php, bash, command

I have a problem, is this possible to run the bash command from PHP level?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of functions exist, allowing you to have the precision level you want.

The only way to choose is to read the doc for these functions.

I post you some links to read :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute a command from php you can do it using the native function system() or exec().
For example if you would like execute bash command uname -a, with system call:

```
$output = system("uname -a", $status);
```

second argument is optionally; if it's present, return the status of the executed command.
For more details i suggest you to take a look to follow php man pages

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php